# How to model data in firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have a very basic question about firebase. Lets say we have users and each users have cats. I keep this data as usercat-data:{user1key:{cat1,cat2}, user2key:{cat3,cat4}}.

If I want to fetch all cats, what should I do? I can think of two possible solutions.

1) Fetch all users keys and make another request to fetch cats. This sound tedious

2) Keep cats under cat-data as well. But maintaining duplicate object will be a problem.

PS: I use angularfire2 library. AFAIK, it doesnt profile an easy solution to my problem.

Please advise what to do.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

you can put cats under a table and use the unique id values as refernce to the user table that might help you